# MySQL spring framework port to Apache Derby: Remove quotes in SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, quotes

I'm trying to port an app from MySQL to Apache Derby. The system uses the Spring framework. What I am finding is that the system sends SQL like "Select blah from table where myint = '123'.

I want to change that to just 123 without the quotes - can anyone tell me how to do this? I can open it up in NetBeans, but I am new to this area.

It's based here https://github.com/TGAC/TGACBrowser.

Any ideas, URLs, references and/or suggestions appreciated.

Paul...

Comment: Can you tell us, where in the code (which package.class) in the git repository one can find the query?

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for your interest - I think that it's here uk.ac.bbsrc.tgac.browser.store.ensembl there are several SQL_something.java files - I did search on ', but can't seem to find the code in question. Is the quoting part of Spring or in my app? Paul...

Comment: Just to add - I've searched for SELECT in the java files mentioned above and found loads of lines, but the problem is that all the SQL is parameterised - from my example above, what I'm seeing is "Select blah from table where myint = ?" and I have no idea how to strip the quotes from the parameter.

Comment: This quotes seams to be set somewhere deep in the Derby PreparedStatement class. Does the cause some problem, or is it just that YOU do not like them?

Comment: @Ralph - thanks again. No, it's not Derby that's the problem. It's the original system which uses MySQL! The original system puts the quotes around integers which is not standard SQL! Derby rejects (rightly) these quotes (select blah from table where myint = '123' is wrong!). I want to find out where these quotes are coming from in the app so I can remove them for my Derby port. They are showing up as cannot cast varchar to int... in the log any thoughts?